# Using P4JAVA with JDK6 on Unix: Client.sync() ignores the execute bit

Tags: perforce, p4java

1. Using p4java-2011.1.297684 with Java 6 on Solaris
2. Running p4 sync -f on the given file will sync the file w/ the execute bit set correctly.
3. Calling client.sync(List, true, false, false, false) does NOT set the execute bit.
4. I also tried implementing my own ISystemFileCommandsHelper and registering it (as opposed to the default):

   ServerFactory.setRpcFileSystemHelper(new MySystemFileCommandsHelper());

   ...

   public class MySystemFileCommandsHelper implements ISystemFileCommandsHelper {

   ...

   ```
   public boolean setExecutable(String file, boolean executable, boolean ownerOnly) {
       File f = new File(file);

       System.out.println("Calling... 2");
       return f.setExecutable(executable, ownerOnly);
   }
   ```

   ...
   }

But also no luck; I also don't see anything logged or printed.

Is there a setting or property that controls the use of the SystemFileCommandsHelper?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What's the Perforce file type of the file in question?  I think it should work correctly for *text+x* or *binary+x* files, but it looks like there's a bug where unicode files (file type *unicode+x*) won't have the executable bit set.

Comment: This file is tagged as ASCII text; i.e., "xtext".

Comment: Hmm, I can't reproduce the problem on a Fedora Linux system.  (I don't have easy access to a Solaris box.)  Might be worth asking Perforce Support about it.